# Open/close input radio

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button, show-hide

I explained my problem, I have an overlay that I used to delete the categories. I add an action to let you choose where to go when the job categories will be deleted.

For this, I use checkbox and I add a javascript function "open" a form when the checkbox is click,
here is an exemple box close:

[image: First box]

here is an exemple box open:

[image: second box]

My html code:

```
  <form method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="cat_action" value="delete" /> Delete all tracks<br />
    <input type="radio" name="cat_action" value="move" onclick="showMe('div_<?php echo $value->ID ?>', this)" /> Move tracks<br />

    <div id="div_<?php echo $value->ID ?>" style="display:none">
    <label for="track">Move tracks to: </label>
    <select id="cate" name="cate">
    <?php foreach (arrayToObject($startup->getCat()) as $value) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value->ID ?>"><?php echo $value->post_title ?></option>
    <?php } ?>  
    </select> <br />        
    </div><br />    

    <button type="submit"> OK </button>
    <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
  </form>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe (it, box) {
var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
}
</script>
```

**My problem:**
When the checkbox opens the list, it does not close when I click on first checkbox.
I just want to create a function that closes the second checkbox.

You can try it here: http://jsbin.com/usituv/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that you don't do anything on the "Delete" option selection - only on "move" selection.  Below is how I updated your script to work properly (provided I understand what you're after).  Specifically note the changes:

- Adding `id` attribute to the *move* radio button
- Adding `onclick` handler to the *delete* radio button
- Changing javascript function to accept only one parameter
- Using `getElementById` function to retrieve the reference to the *move* radio button inside the javascript function.

Also note that it would be better to separate all your javascript into a separate file, including assigning the `onclick` handlers.  However I'm simply fixing your problem at hand here.

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="cat_action" value="delete"
           onclick="showMe('div_1')"/> Delete all tracks<br />
    <input type="radio" name="cat_action" value="move"
           onclick="showMe('div_1')" id="move"/> Move tracks<br />

    <div id="div_1" style="display:none">
        <label for="paypal">Move tracks to: </label>
        <select id="cate" name="cate">
            <option value="dubstep">Dubstep</option>
            <option value="breakbeat">Breakbeat</option>
            <option value="dnb">D'n'B</option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <br />

    <button type="submit"> OK </button>
    <button type="button" class="close"> Cancel </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe (it) {
        var box = document.getElementById("move");
        var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
        document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: your explanation is very clear and it work. Obviously, I separate all my javascript in an external file, here, it is just for the developement. Thanks for your explanation and your help Aleks ;)